# Iterating through table columns

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a table named Table1 in Sheet("Controle Locatário X Imóvel"), that i want to check given the values of the Locatario and Imovel variables, if they are in the same row, and, if the Locatario matches and the imovel doesn't, that substitute the value of the cell for the value in the variable.

I searched many different solutions, but doesn't find anything very useful --'

```
Sub AssociarLocatarioImovel()
    
    'Definição das variáveis
    Dim Cell
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim Locatario As String
    Dim Imovel As String
    
    Locatario = Sheets("Controle Locatário X Imóvel").Range("F3").Value
    Imovel = Sheets("Controle Locatário X Imóvel").Range("F6").Value
    MyRange = Sheets("Tabela").Range("Table1[Locatário]").Column
    
    For Each Cell In MyRange
        
        If Cell.Value = Locatario Then
        
            If Sheets("Tabela").Range("Table1[Imóvel]") <> Imovel Then
            
                Sheets("Tabela").Range("Table1[Imóvel]") = Imovel
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub AssociarLocatarioImovel()
    Dim Cell
    Dim Locatario As String
    Dim Imovel As String
    
    Locatario = Sheets("Controle Locatário X Imóvel").Range("F3").Value
    Imovel = Sheets("Controle Locatário X Imóvel").Range("F6").Value
    Set RngLocatário = Sheets("Tabela").Range("Table1[Locatário]")
    Set RngImóvel = Sheets("Tabela").Range("Table1[Imóvel]")
    TopRow = RngLocatário.Cells(0).Row
    
    For Each Cell In RngLocatário
        If Cell.Value = Locatario Then
            If RngImóvel(Cell.Row - TopRow, 1) <> Imovel Then
                RngImóvel(Cell.Row - TopRow, 1) = Imovel
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Provide more details about the excel file. If you can upload it somewhere, that would be better.

Comment: https://github.com/carlosefrbarros/Email-Sender-System I uploaded the file